# OS not found by BIOS

Tags: ssd, bios, operating-systems

Win10 w/ASUS Z97 MB.  Cloned OS on to new SSD, BIOS sees the SSD in the boot list of drives.  But choosing boot priority does not show up.  ??

What can I do to make BIOS see the SSD in Boot priority chooses?

Comment: usually boot priority only shows device types. There's probably a seperate menu for "hard disk priority" which includes your ssd

Comment: Do you have more then one OS booitng up on different drives or is there only one? You should be able to boot up to it. As explained above its going to show you the options to boot off of in a priority which if you chose Hard Drive it would boot off your SSD if its the one with the bootable OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the BIOS sees the disk, then it can boot from it, providing that it's
formatted correctly and has a functional boot-sector.

If the BIOS is actually a UEFI firmware then the disk must be formatted as GPT.
For an MBR disk, UEFI firmware must be set to boot in what's usually called
legacy-mode.
For a BIOS system, the disk must be formatted as MBR.

Cloning a disk does not guarantee that it is usable, especially when the
old and new disk-sizes are not identical. Proper partition-alignment is also
very important for SSD in order to avoid the premature wear-down of the disk.

I would suggest that instead of cloning, to use a specialized HDD-to-SDD
product, that will take care of all these details.
This does not guarantee the disk being bootable, so a refresh of the
boot-code might be required. Boot-repair normally requires a boot
CD or USB.

See the article [How to Upgrade Your Laptop’s Hard Drive to an SSD](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/ssd-upgrade-tutorial)
which uses [EaseUS Todo backup Free](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/download.htm), but it's not the only such product.

Comment: Now working.  SSD is seen using legacy-mode.  Thanks for the help.